# Checkbox subcategories hidden until parent checkbox selected

Tags: checkbox, parent, categories

I'm trying to get subcategory checkboxes to only display once the relevant parent checkbox has been selected.

At the moment I'm using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#listing_category-401 .children").css("display", "none");
$(".option").change(function () {

    if ($('checkbox[id="in-listing_category-401"] :checked').val() == "true") {
        $("#listing_category-401 .children").slideDown("fast");
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Any suggestions? Do you need more info from me?

Comment: Relevant HTML would be nice. Where is the problem? If you console.log("test") in the .val() == "true" does that fire? Provide a fiddle or your html and we can resolve quickly.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your response. Please see the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c59s6qsb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, approached it slightly differently, but the following will work, heres the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pxt4x7q1/

And here's the code:

HTML

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <li id="listing_category-401"><label class="selectit"><input value="401" type="checkbox" class="required option" name="_listing_category[]" id="in-listing_category-401" aria-required="true"> Artists/Bands</label>
  <ul class="children">
  <li id="listing_category-399"><label class="selectit"><input value="399" type="checkbox" class="required" name="_listing_category[]" id="in-listing_category-399" aria-required="true"> Acoustic Artists/Bands</label></li>
  <li id="listing_category-402"><label class="selectit"><input value="402" type="checkbox" class="required" name="_listing_category[]"  id="in-listing_category-402" aria-required="true"> Alternative Artists/Bands</label></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
```

STYLE:

```
  <style TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
  .children {
    display:none
  }
  </style>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#in-listing_category-401').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
             $("#listing_category-401 .children").slideDown("fast");
        }
        else {
          $("#listing_category-401 .children").slideUp("fast");
        }
    })
  })
  </script>
```

Comment: Bud you are an absolute legend! Thank you!

Comment: One last thing if you're willing to help again - I'm trying to disable all parent categories when clicking on 1 parent category. I have the following fiddle which works fine here (http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/rn6Va/) but doesn't work fine on my fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/c59s6qsb/16/)